# Python How Can I Scrape Image URL and Image Title From This Link With BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I could not reach the image url and image title with Beautiful soup. I will be glad if you help me. Thanks

The image url I want to scrape is:
https://cdn.homebnc.com/homeimg/2017/01/29-entry-table-ideas-homebnc.jpg

Title I want to scrape
37 Best Entry Table Ideas (Decorations and Designs) for 2017

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36',
}
response = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=sg67yP87&id=39EC3D95F0FC25C52E714B1776D819AB564D474B&thid=OIP.sg67yP87Kr9hQF8PiKnKZQHaLG&mediaurl=https%3a%2f%2fcdn.homebnc.com%2fhomeimg%2f2017%2f01%2f29-entry-table-ideas-homebnc.jpg&cdnurl=https%3a%2f%2fth.bing.com%2fth%2fid%2fR.b20ebbc8ff3b2abf61405f0f88a9ca65%3frik%3dS0dNVqsZ2HYXSw%26pid%3dImgRaw%26r%3d0&exph=2247&expw=1500&q=table+ideas&simid=608015185750411203&FORM=IRPRST&ck=7EA9EDE471AB12F7BDA2E7DA12DC56C9&selectedIndex=0&qft=+filterui%3aimagesize-large", headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup is only giving you the html format before any scripts are executed. For this reason you should try to scrape the website with a combination of Selenium and BeautifulSoup. Selenium can be used to simulate a browser, which in turn will render the scripts on the website to actual html code. This html code can be passed into BeautifulSoup in order to scrape the image and title.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above by @Carst3n, BeautifulSoup is only giving you the html format before any scripts are executed. For this reason you should try to scrape the website with a combination of Selenium and BeautifulSoup.

You can download chromedriver from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

opts = Options()
opts.add_argument(" --headless")
opts.add_argument("--log-level=3")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH_TO_CHROME_DRIVER, options=opts)

driver.get("https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=sg67yP87&id=39EC3D95F0FC25C52E714B1776D819AB564D474B&thid=OIP.sg67yP87Kr9hQF8PiKnKZQHaLG&mediaurl=https%3a%2f%2fcdn.homebnc.com%2fhomeimg%2f2017%2f01%2f29-entry-table-ideas-homebnc.jpg&cdnurl=https%3a%2f%2fth.bing.com%2fth%2fid%2fR.b20ebbc8ff3b2abf61405f0f88a9ca65%3frik%3dS0dNVqsZ2HYXSw%26pid%3dImgRaw%26r%3d0&exph=2247&expw=1500&q=table+ideas&simid=608015185750411203&FORM=IRPRST&ck=7EA9EDE471AB12F7BDA2E7DA12DC56C9&selectedIndex=0&qft=+filterui%3aimagesize-large")
time.sleep(2)
soup_file = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(soup_file)
print(soup.select('#mainImageWindow .nofocus')[0].get('src'))
print(soup.select('.novid')[0].string)
```